# Why can't I boot in UEFI Mode?

Tags: boot, ssd, uefi

I just upgraded my computer from a HDD to an SSD. When I boot my computer with the new SSD, it must be in the legacy boot mode, or it will fail to start. My old drive was UEFI, but now that option fails. Is there anything I can do or do I just need to keep it in Legacy? Running Windows 10 64 bit, Lenovo Y700.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

I read the comments on partition type and I will check on that.  Is there an easy way to change the partition type?  I did a fresh install of Windows on the SSD.

UPDATE 2

It seems to me that it would take a lot of effort for me to change the partition type.  I will decide whether I want to put in the time to backup and restore, but thank you all for your help. In the scheme of things it is probably a minor problem.

Comment: Have you installed an OS on the SSD?

Comment: Yes, I thought I made that clear, I have windows 10 64 bit installed on both the SSD and the HDD.  I can only boot to the SSD in Legacy mode, though.

Comment: Did you actually install it on the SSD or did you clone it from the old drive?

Comment: check the system partition is it GPT or MBR ? mostly if you have a MBR partition, the UEFI system will fail to boot, so you need to convert the partition to GPT to fix this issue.check this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825112.aspx

Comment: To install a Windows that is UEFI bootable, when you boot the installation medium you need to boot it in UEFI mode as well.

Comment: The **only** reason Windows would only boot with Leagcy mode enabled would be if the Windows installation was installed on a MBR partition.  Update your question to include this information

Comment: You said you "did a fresh install of Windows on the SSD." If that's true -- that is, if you booted a Windows installation medium and ran through the regular Windows installation process -- then all bets are off as to what the boot mode would be. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on why this is. (My page is geared towards Linux and Windows/Linux dual-boots, but the same principles apply to Windows-only installs.)